# Cyclic dependency of modules

Tags: f#

I want to write a parser in F# and because of reasons I have to use Antlr. This means I have to define a `Visitor` class for every AST node I want to parse. Now I have the problem that there are some rules with cyclic dependencies like:

```
boolExpr : boolTerm 'or' boolTerm ;
boolTerm : boolAtom 'and' boolAtom ;
boolAtom : '(' boolExpr ')' 
         | ... ;
```

which means I need 3 visitor classes that have the same cyclic dependency and I want to have each of them in their own file

```
//BoolExprVisitor.fs
let boolExprVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolExpr>() with
    override __.VisitBoolExpr(context: BoolExprContext) =
        context.boolTerm() |> mapAccept boolTermVisitor |> AST.BoolExpr
}

//BoolTermVisitor.fs
let boolTermVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolTerm>() with
    override __.VisitBoolTerm(context: BoolTermContext) =
        context.boolAtom() |> mapAccept boolAtomVisitor |> AST.BoolTerm
}

//BoolAtomVisitor.fs
let boolAtomVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolAtom>() with
    override __.VisitBoolAtom(context: BoolAtomContext) =
        context.boolExpr() |> accept boolExprVisitor |> AST.BoolAtom
}
```

But F# doesn't like these cyclic dependencies. How can I make F# accept them or restructure my visitors to not need cyclid dependencies?

Comment: Mutually recursive types and functions are defined with `and` rather than a new `type`/`let`: would that work in this case?

Comment: `and` won't work because I want the classes in different files and F# does not seem to like `and` if I have anonymous types like my visitors

Comment: Have you read https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/ and its two follow-up articles? See also https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/ for an explanation of why "I want the classes in different files" is not a good fit for F#. F# encourages you to group *similar functionality* together in one file, instead of one file = one class. I don't think you'll find a solution unless you accept that anything with circular dependencies needs to be in the same file.

Comment: Offtopic: But looked at FParsec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this problem in the future: 
As rmunn said, the fact that I wanted the classes in different files was simply not good design. Also I did not need different AST nodes for `BoolTerm`, `BoolAtom` and `BoolExpr` as they could all be described as the same node `BoolExpr`.

My solution was to merge all of the boolean expression visitors into the same class (and merge all files for expression visitors into a single file):

```
//AST.fs
type BoolExpr = 
    | BoolConjunctionExpr of BoolOp * BoolExpr list
    | ...

//ExpressionVisitors.fs
let boolExprVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolExpr>() with
    override this.VisitBoolExpr(context: BoolExprContext) =
        context.boolTerm() |> mapAccept this |> AST.BoolConjunctionExpr AST.Or

    override this.VisitBoolTerm(context: BoolTermContext) =
        context.boolAtom() |> mapAccept this |> AST.BoolConjunctionExpr AST.And

    override this.VisitBoolAtom(context: BoolAtomContext) =
        context.boolExpr() |> accept this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't want to create the visitor instances at the same time using `and` you have to resort to mutable variables. Create a mutable variable for one of the visitors with the value as unchecked default of its type. Then when you have the actual instance assign it to the variable.

```
//BoolExprVisitor.fs
module BoolExprVisitor =
    let mutable boolTermVisitor = Unchecked.defaultof<BaseVisitor<AST.BoolTerm>>

    let boolExprVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolExpr>() with
        override __.VisitBoolExpr(context: BoolExprContext) =
            context.boolTerm() |> mapAccept boolTermVisitor |> AST.BoolExpr
    }

//BoolAtomVisitor.fs
module BoolAtomVisitor =
    open BoolExprVisitor
    let boolAtomVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolAtom>() with
        override __.VisitBoolAtom(context: BoolAtomContext) =
            context.boolExpr() |> accept boolExprVisitor |> AST.BoolAtom
    }


//BoolTermVisitor.fs
module BoolTermVisitor
    open BoolAtomVisitor

    let boolTermVisitor = { new BaseVisitor<AST.BoolTerm>() with
        override __.VisitBoolTerm(context: BoolTermContext) =
            context.boolAtom() |> mapAccept boolAtomVisitor |> AST.BoolTerm
    }

    BoolExprVisitor.boolTermVisitor <- boolTermVisitor
```

Note that this is essentially the same thing as using `createParserForwardedToRef` in FParsec.