# Cyclic dependency between modules when creating JSON tree

Tags: f#

I develop a library that creates JSON Hyperschema for a given class using reflection. I chose F# as programming language, but don't have much experience with it.

Like others ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755391/cyclic-dependency-of-modules) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904889/f-mutual-recursion-between-modules) question), I face the problem that I would like to create a cyclic dependency between modules, but I can't...

The library's main function should be given a `Type` and returns a `JsonSchema`.

```ml
type JsonSchema = {
    Type: JsonType
    Links: seq<LinkDescriptor>
}
```

A `JsonType` is a primitive, array, object, or nullable. But an array has an `items` field of the type `JsonSchema`, and an object has a list of `JsonProperties`, which again reference `JsonSchema`.

```ml
type JsonType =
    | JsonBoolean
    | JsonInteger
    | JsonNumber
    | JsonString
    | JsonArray of items: JsonSchema
    | JsonObject of properties: seq<JsonProperty>
    | Nullable of underlyingType: JsonType
```

```ml
type JsonProperty = {
    Schema: JsonSchema
    Name: string
}
```

Then there is the `LinkDescriptor` type used in `JsonSchema`, which, again, has a field of type `JsonSchema`.

```ml
type LinkDescriptor = {
    Rel: string
    Href: UriTemplate
    HrefSchema: JsonSchema option
}
```

If I took this approach and just wrote all types in one file and linked them with `and`, I would be forced to make the functions that create the types mutually recursive.

```ml
let rec getJsonType (t: Type): JsonType =
    // Handle primitive types
    if (t.IsArray) then
        let itemsType = t.GetElementType()
        let schema = {
            Type = getJsonType itemsType
            Links = getLinksForType itemsType
        }
        JsonArray schema
    else JsonObject <| getJsonProperties t

and getJsonProperties (t: Type): seq<JsonProperty> =
    getPublicProperties t
    |> Seq.map (fun p -> {
           Name = p.Name
           Schema = {
               Type = getJsonType p.PropertyType
               Links = getLinksForProperty p
           }
       })

and getLinksForType (t: Type): seq<LinkDescriptor> =
    getLinkAttributes t
    |> Seq.map (fun attr -> {
           Rel = attr.Rel
           Href = attr.Href
           HrefSchema =
               if isNull attr.HrefSchemaType
               then None
               else Some { Type = getJsonType attr.HrefSchemaType; Links = Seq.empty<LinkDescriptor> }
       })
```

In reality, these functions are a bit more complex, which is why I want them to be in different modules.

I have read [Refactoring to remove cyclic dependencies](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/removing-cyclic-dependencies/#dealing-with-a-structural-dependency), but don't know how parameterization could be applied in my case.

The only idea I could come up with is the following: Instead of creating the complete JSON tree all at once, I only create one layer at a time. That is, the `JsonType` stores the underlying `System.Type`:

```ml
type JsonType =
    | JsonBoolean
    // ...
    | JsonArray of Type
    | JsonObject of Type
    | Nullable of underlyingType: JsonType
```

Then I could create a `JsonType` module that contains functions like `getItemsSchema`, which retrieves the `JsonSchema` on the basis of the stored type of the `JsonArray`. The same goes for `getObjectProperties`.

But I am not really happy with this approach, because it feels a bit like a leaky abstraction.

**Do you have any suggestions how I can improve above code in order to get rid of the cyclic dependencies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the logic of your functions is tightly coupled I think they should remain in the same module.

However, if you still want to break them up you can do as follows:

Imagine that you have the following set of functions dependent on each other:

```
let rec f x = g x + h x
and g x = f x
and h x = f x
```

In order to declare each one of the in their own module, you could define explicitly their function dependencies.   For example function f is dependent on function g and h:

```
module moduleF = 
   let _f (g:int->int) (h:int->int) x = g x + h x
```

You can do the same for g and h, while having them implemented in different modules:

```
module moduleG = 
       let _g (f:int->int) x = f x

module moduleH =
       let _h (f:int->int) x = f x
```

Finally, you can integrate them all in a fourth module, providing the necessary dependencies for each of your functions.

```
module Final = 
    open ModuleF
    open ModuleG
    open ModuleH


    let rec f x = _f g h x
    and g x = _g f x
    and h x = _h f x
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! I created functions like `getLinksForType (t: Type) (getSchema: Type -> JsonSchema): seq<LinkDescriptor>´, which can now be in separate modules.